# How can I control an Android VM?

Tags: java, android

I have the eclipse android SDK. It comes with an android emulator. When I run an application, eclipse installs the newest version of the app and runs it on the emulator, by default. How can I write a program to control an android VM (or actual device connected via USB since they work the same way)? I want to be able to externally issue commands to an emulator, not simply simulate clicks.

Comment: What commands do you want? The ADB Shell supports a few basic commands

Comment: I want to be able to kill applications and run new applications. How can I use the ADB shell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:<your app package>`.tell me is it working for you.is there is a other way too `adb shell pm uninstall -k + yourpackagename`